# Обновления в google play

Tags: android

Доброго времени суток! После того как я выложил первое приложение на маркет, теперь возникло желание кое-что обновить и добавить в приложение. Каким образом работают обновления? в приложении есть база данных и shared preference. что будет с ними? после обновления они удалятся? и как вообще сделать по-нормальному?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

в манифесте нужно увеличить номер (`android:versionCode`), хотя бы на `+1`. И можно заливать в маркет.

> в приложении есть база данных и shared preference. что будет с ними? после обновления они удалятся?

А зачем им это делать. все будет. Главное, что бы обновленное приложение могло правильно со "старой базой" работать - иногда ведь в новой версии обновляется структура, появляются новые поля.

Comment: структуру базы не изменил. насчет версии - я поменял на 1. вроде должно все работать